# T-SQL, list of DATETIME, create <from> - <to> from it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, common-table-expression

What would I need to do to achieve the following? Somehow I can't seem to find a good solution.

I have a few CTEs, and the last one is producing just a list of `DATETIME` values, with a row number column, and those are ordered by the `DATETIME`.

For example

```
rn  datetime
---------------------------
1   2023-01-07 01:00:00.000
2   2023-01-08 05:30:00.000
3   2023-01-08 08:00:00.000
4   2023-01-09 21:30:00.000
```

How do I have to join this CTE with each other in order to get the following result:

```
from                        to
---------------------------------------------------
2023-01-07 01:00:00.000     2023-01-08 05:30:00.000
2023-01-08 08:00:00.000     2023-01-09 21:30:00.000
```

Doing a regular inner join (with `t1.rn = t2.rn - 1`) gives me one row too much (the one from 05:30 to 08:00). So basically each date can only be "used" once.

Hope that makes sense... thanks!

Inner joining the CTE with itself, which didn't return the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot the outcome of your CTE and distribute rows using arithmetics : modulo 2 comes to mind.

Assuming that your CTE returns columns `dt` (a datetime field) and `rn` (an integer row number) :

```
select min(dt) dt_from, max(dt) dt_to
from cte 
group by ( rn - 1 ) % 2
```

On T-SQL we could also leverage integer division to express the pair grouping:

```
group by ( rn - 1 ) / 2
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. group by ( rn - 1 ) / 2 does work! 

I just did the following myself, which also seems to work, but yours is far less code and far cooler ;-)

SELECT *
FROM cte2 t1
OUTER APPLY (
 SELECT *
 FROM cte2 t2
 WHERE rn % 2 = 0
 ) t2
WHERE t1.rn % 2 = 1
 AND t1.rn = t2.rn - 1

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid both the JOIN and the GROUP BY by using `LAG` to retrieve a previous column value in the result set. The server may be able to generate an execution plan that iterates over the data just once instead of joining or grouping :

```
with pairs as (
    SELECT rn, lag(datetime) OVER(ORDER BY rn) as dt_from, datetime as dt_to
    from another_cte        
)
select dt_from,dt_to
from pairs
ORDER BY rn
where rn%2=0
```

The row number itself can be calculated from `datetime` :

```
with pairs as (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY datetime) AS rn,
        lag(datetime) OVER(ORDER BY datetime) as dt_from, 
        datetime as dt_to
    from another_cte  
)
select dt_from,dt_to
from pairs
ORDER BY dt_to
where rn%2=0
```