# Create <from>-<to> list with DATETIMEs, Maximum pause between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I posted a question a few days ago ([T-SQL, list of DATETIME, create <from> - <to> from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062818/t-sql-list-of-datetime-create-from-to-from-it))  regarding taking a list of DATETIME and converting that to a list of  - .

I thought my initial T-SQL code that created that list of DATETIMEs was working correctly, turns out it doesn't for "edge cases".

What I'm trying to achieve:

I have an initial list of DATETIMEs. As my result I want to get a list of <from_dt> - <to_dt> with the restriction that between to dates/times there is a maximum of @maxDiff (INT) minutes between them. So, if we have the following list of DATETIMEs and a maxDiff of e.g. 100 minutes:

```
2022-01-01 13:00:00.000
2022-01-01 14:00:00.000
2022-01-01 15:00:00.000
```

the result should be:

```
from                        to
2022-01-01 13:00:00.000     2022-01-01 15:00:00.000
```

I do have this working for "easy cases" using the following code. But, my problem now is that this doesn't do for example for the following edge case that you can also find in the following code:

```
DECLARE @maxDiff INT = 100;

DECLARE @datesTmp TABLE (   
    t DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @datesTmp 
VALUES 
('2022-01-01 13:00:00'),
('2022-01-02 14:00:00'),
('2022-01-03 15:00:00')

DECLARE @dates TABLE (
    rn INT
    ,t DATETIME
    ,d INT
    )

INSERT INTO @dates
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY t
        ) rn
    ,t
    ,datediff(minute, t, lead(t) OVER (
            ORDER BY t
            )) d
FROM @datesTmp

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @dates
    WHERE d IS NULL
        OR d > @maxDiff
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT *
    FROM @dates
    WHERE rn IN (
            SELECT rn + 1
            FROM @dates
            WHERE d > @maxDiff
            )
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @dates
    WHERE rn = 1
    )
    ,cte2
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY t
            ) rn
        ,t
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT min(t) tFrom
    ,max(t) tTo
FROM cte2
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 2
```

The result will be:

```
from                        to
2022-01-01 13:00:00.000     2022-01-02 14:00:00.000
2022-01-03 15:00:00.000     2022-01-03 15:00:00.000
```

So in those cases my @maxDiff will not be used basically.

In those cases from and to should be the same:

```
from                        to
2022-01-01 13:00:00.000     2022-01-01 13:00:00.000 
2022-01-02 14:00:00.000     2022-01-02 14:00:00.000 
2022-01-03 15:00:00.000     2022-01-03 15:00:00.000
```

I can't wrap my head around how to do this correctly/best. Any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

I hope that can be found in the question itself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my question wasn't asked properly or was hard to understand. I think I might have solved my problem on my own. It might not be the proper way to handle the issue, but it seems to be working, so far (even though I wouldn't be surprised if I haven't looked at all possible "edge cases" :-)).

My solution is now using LAG/LEAD a lot to look at the datedifferences between rows, then giving each date/time a kind of "type" (start, end, startEnd (both)). Using those I afterwards use a CTE to basically double those startEnd entries, and then in the end use the grouping by row number code that I got in my other thread.

So here is my code, for anyone that's interested:

```
DECLARE @maxDiff INT = 100;
DECLARE @datesTmp TABLE (dt DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @datesTmp
VALUES ('2022-01-01 12:15:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 12:30:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 12:45:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 13:00:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 14:00:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 15:00:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 15:30:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 16:30:00')
    ,('2022-01-01 18:30:00')

DECLARE @dates TABLE (
    dt DATETIME
    ,t NVARCHAR(12)
    )

INSERT INTO @dates
SELECT dt
    ,CASE 
        WHEN lag(dt) OVER (
                ORDER BY dt
                ) IS NULL
            AND datediff(minute, dt, lead(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    )) > @maxDiff
            THEN 'startEnd'
        WHEN (
                lag(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    ) IS NULL
                OR datediff(minute, lag(dt) OVER (
                        ORDER BY dt
                        ), dt) > @maxDiff
                )
            AND datediff(minute, dt, lead(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    )) <= @maxDiff
            THEN 'start'
        WHEN (
                lead(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    ) IS NULL
                OR datediff(minute, dt, lead(dt) OVER (
                        ORDER BY dt
                        )) > @maxDiff
                )
            AND datediff(minute, lag(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    ), dt) > @maxDiff
            THEN 'startEnd'
        WHEN (
                lead(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    ) IS NULL
                OR datediff(minute, dt, lead(dt) OVER (
                        ORDER BY dt
                        )) > @maxDiff
                )
            AND datediff(minute, lag(dt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY dt
                    ), dt) <= @maxDiff
            THEN 'end'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS t
FROM @datesTmp
ORDER BY dt

DELETE
FROM @dates
WHERE t IS NULL

--SELECT *
--FROM @dates;

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @dates d1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT *
    FROM @dates d2
    WHERE d2.t = 'startEnd'
    )
    ,cte2
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY dt
            ) rn
        ,dt
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT min(dt) tFrom
    ,max(dt) tTo
FROM cte2
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 2
```